# bash hash command in .bashrc file does not affect global environment

Tags: bash, hash

In my .bashrc file I have the following two commands:

```
hash ih kl klt
hash
```

When the .bashrc file is sourced, the output is as expected:

```
hits    command
   0    /userdata/cfor/utils/worklib/kl
   0    /userdata/cfor/utils/prodlib/ih
   0    /opt/local/tools/bin/vi
```

But then afterwards when I enter "hash" at the command prompt it tells me that the hash table is empty.  It's as if the effect of the hash instructions lives only while the .bashrc file is being sourced.  I put an "echo $$" instruction in the .bashrc file and then checked the value of $$ after the sourcing had completed, and they were the same.  Why don't the effects of the hash command persist after the .bashrc file is finished being sourced?

Thanks!

Comment: What else is in your `.bashrc`? Are you modifying `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, but only at the top of the .bashrc file.  The hash instruction comes only after all path edits have been completed.  There are function definitions that follow the hash command but they have nothing to do with the commands that the hash command addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.  I found that my sysadmin had introduced a link in the /etc/profile file to another script that caused the .bashrc file to be sourced as one of several in a series.  That is quite different from the way dot files are automatically sourced in the default environment.  At any rate, one of the "extra" scripts was resetting the PATH, which causes the command hash table to reinitialize.  I found that even with my company's modifications the ~/.bash_profile file was still the last file to be sourced, so I put my hash instruction in there.  Then, after I had logged out and back in again, the results of the hash instruction persisted.

Thank you for your replies, they helped guide to where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source `~/.bashrc` from either `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. When invoked as a login shell, as happens for me when I open a new terminal, bash does not source `~/.bashrc`.

Take a look at the [documentation for Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files).